# WhatsApp web option not displayed in WhatsApp iPhone

Tags: whatsapp.app

I have an iPhone 4S with WhatsApp.

I install WhatsApp Web on my PC. It starts, and displays a QR code.  I'm supposed to use my iPhone's WhatsApp to scan the Qr code. The menu item to do this is supposed to be in "settings". When I open "settings" I don't see the option. It's supposed to be below "tell a friend".

[image]

What do I need to do to get the option to appear?

The option should be appearing in the iPhone software "WhatsApp"; it is missing from that software as installed on my device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have an old iOS version on your iPhone. In order to use WhatsApp Web, you should have at least iOS 8.1 installed on your iPhone. (https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/web/28080003)

In order to update your iPhone, go to Settings > General > Software Update > Install Update.

Comment: The claim that it is because of an outdated version of ios is false. I have iOs 11.2.1, the latest version, and "Web" is missing under Whatsapp on my iphone as well.

Comment: Habibi, in Leopoldo's case, it was correct. In your case, however, I don't know what's the problem.

Did you go to Settings but couldn't find "Web"? Maybe this article will help: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/web/28080003/